Automatically synchronize two audio streams with ffmpeg
Say I have a video of a talk but the soundtrack is bad, and I happen to have an audio recording of the same talk made with a good mike. Is there a way, with ffmpeg, to replace the bad audio with the good one, automatically synchronizing the two (the good mike was not started at the same time as the camera, and I don’t want to manually specify the shift)?
Can ffmpeg do that? I have found many questions about swapping/merging audio streams, but not much about synchronizing them first.

try -itsoffset → ffmpeg -i "0.mp4" -itsoffset -1.12 -i "1.mp4" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy "out.mp4"

@БаярГончикжапов But that’s not automatic synchronizing, right? I need to manually calculate the offset with this solution?

Ah, yes, I'm sorry. I didn't understand request.

I use the free version of DaVinci Resolve to do my video editing, including automatically aligning my separately recorded audio to my video. But I don't know whether this is a built-in function of ffmpeg.

@music2myear ah yeah and I use Adobe Premiere to do the same thing usually, but I’d like to do everything from the command line now!
